# Table and FindMinimum

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I have a function where I want to find its minimal value for some parameters. I tried to use `FindMinimum` separately for each function given some values of the parameters and successfully found the minimal values, but when I use a combination of `Table` and `FindMinimum`, it failed to give me a value since it produces an error saying,

`FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value functionSL[0.01,0.8,zh] is not a real number at {zl} = {0.8}.`

My code is as follows,

```
d = 3;
torootL[a_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := a - NIntegrate[(c zl^(d + 1) xd^(d/(d + 1)))/((1 - xd (zl/zh)^(d + 1)) (1 - xd^((2 d)/(d + 1)) c^2 (zl)^(2 d)))^(1/2), {xd, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> "DoubleExponential"}]
cz[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := c /. FindRoot[torootL[a, c, zl, zh], {c, 0.001, 0.0000001, 1000}]
intSL[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[With[{b = zl/zh}, (((-1)/(d - 1)) cz[a, zl, zh]^2 zl^(2 d)) x^d ((1 - (b x)^(d + 1))/(1 - cz[a, zl, zh]^2 (zl x)^(2 d)))^(1/2) - ((b^(d + 1) (d + 1))/(2 (d - 1))) x ((1 - cz[a, zl, zh]^2 (zl x)^(2 d))/(1 - (b x)^(d + 1)))^(1/2) + (b^(d + 1)x)/((1 - (b x)^(d + 1)) (1 - cz[a, zl, zh]^2 (zl x)^(2 d)))^(1/2)], {x, 0, 1}, MaxRecursion -> 12, PrecisionGoal -> 6, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> "DoubleExponential"}]
functionSL[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] = ((-((1 - cz[a, zl, zh]^2 zl^(2 d)) (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1)))^(1/2)/(d - 1)) + intSL[a, zl, zh] + 1)/(4 zl^(d - 1));

FindMinimum[functionSL[0.01, zl, 1], {zl, 0.8, 1}]
FindMinimum[functionSL[0.01, zl, 2], {zl, 1.7, 2}]
FindMinimum[functionSL[0.01, zl, 3], {zl, 2.5, 3}]
FindMinimum[functionSL[0.01, zl, 4], {zl, 3.5, 4}](*this way of writing works*)


Zmin = Table[FindMinimum[functionSL[0.01, zl, zh], {zl, 0.8, 4}], {zh, 1, 4, 1}] // Quiet (*this way does not work*)
```

What mistakes have I done?

Comment: Try this `functionSL[0.01, 1.5, 1]` and you'll see it's not real valued, but a complex number.

Comment: If you don't want to change your expressions or skirt around these values to avoid the complexes, you could change your `functionSL` to give a very large penalty value if there is an imaginary part: `functionSL[a_?NumericQ, zl_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ] := 
 With[{result = ((-((1 - 
               cz[a, zl, zh]^2 zl^(2 d)) (1 - (zl/zh)^(d + 1)))^(1/
             2)/(d - 1)) + intSL[a, zl, zh] + 1)/(4 zl^(d - 1))}, 
  Quiet@If[Im[result] != 0, 999999, result]]` . This then fixes your `Zmin` and I get very similar values in the table to compared to the individual  calls to `FindMinimum`

Comment: I've just realized, it would in fact be much simpler to just add a constraint to the minimization: `Zmin = Table[
   FindMinimum[{functionSL[0.01, zl, zh], zl <= zh}, {zl, 0.8, 
     4}], {zh, 1, 4, 1}] // Quiet (*this way does not work*)` gets you what you need without error.

Comment: @flinty Oh, I never thought that it is the condition `zl<=zh` that is what I am missing because if `zh=1` since the range of `zl` is `[0.8,4]` it will definitely overshoot and result into a complex value. Also, nice technique to make complex values quiet. Thanks!

Comment: @flinty I would also like to plot the minimum values of the `functionSL[0.01,zl,zh]` with respect to `zh` so I wrote `functionSL[0.01, zl, zh] /. Zmin[[1 ;; 5, 2]]` which gave me a list but `zh` still has no value, is there a way to also substitute `zh`?

Comment: Obviously `zh` is missing because it evaluates as a constant in each part of the `Table` _before_ the minimization. But luckily for you the minimum values are already in `Zmin`. They are the first element in each sublist so you can get them from `Zmin[[All, 1]]`. Try plotting: `ListLinePlot[Zmin[[All, 1]], Mesh -> All, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @flinty Your code is correct if `zh` increases by 1, in my code it is given by `{zh,1,5,1}` but what if I want `{zh,1,5,2}` so the increment is 2? The plot will give me values at x-axis values 1,2,3, but it must be 1,3,5 since the increment is 2.

Comment: `Transpose[{Range[1,5,2],Zmin[[All, 1]]}]` will give you a list of pairs `{zh, min}`